# "method redefined" warning: unclear why it exists, unclear if I can fix it on my end

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I added sorbet to a pet project of mine: https://github.com/Trevoke/SGFParser

When I run the tests, I get a lot of the following warning ([here's a link to a travis-ci build](https://travis-ci.org/Trevoke/SGFParser/builds/551005916)):

> /Users/trevoke/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.4.4314/lib/types/private/methods/call_validation.rb:807:
>   warning: method redefined; discarding old add_error
>
> /Users/trevoke/.rbenv/versions/2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-runtime-0.4.4314/lib/types/private/methods/_methods.rb:127:
>   warning: previous definition of add_error was here

Where "add_error" is a method of mine -- the other warnings show different method names.

I'd like to know if this is something which belongs entirely on the sorbet side or whether I can do something to get rid of them.

Comment: I should add, here, for those who are voting to close, that the sorbet project redirected me here ( https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/new/choose ).

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem like you can do anything on your side right now. It *might* be related to [Sorbet#1150](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/1150): "sorbet-runtime causes many warnings with Ruby $VERBOSE mode".

There's an open PR ([Sorbet#1266](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/1266)) that could help.